# Is it possible to obtain an Azure AD V1 token using MSAL?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

I'm currently setting up ADD with MSAL for my app. The issue I am running into is that the api is set to accept Azure AD V1 tokens, but with my current MSAL setup I keep receiving an Azure AD V2.

Other people in my team are using ADAL, but we want to migrate to MSAL. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, as it seems hard to believe there is no backwards compatibility.

This is my Msal Config:

```
import * as Msal from 'msal';

export const applicationConfig = {
    clientID: process.env.REACT_APP_MSAL_CLIENT_ID,
    authority: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHORITY_TENANT,
    graphScopes: ['user.read'],
    graphEndpoint: process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPH_ENDPOINT,
};

/**
 * will get the call back once the API is complete
 * (either complete or failure), redirects flows.
 * Is called after the authentication request is completed
 * successfully/failure
 *
 * @param {*} errorDesc
 * @param {*} token
 * @param {*} error
 * @param {*} tokenType
 */
const tokenReceivedCallback = async (errorDesc, token, errorMsg) => {
    try {
        if (token) console.log('Success!');
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(`${errorMsg}:${errorDesc}`);
    }
};

/**
 * Instantiate UserAgentApplication
 */
const userAgentApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
    applicationConfig.clientID,
    applicationConfig.authority,
    tokenReceivedCallback,
    {
        cacheLocation: process.env.REACT_APP_CACHE_LOCATION,
        redirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI,
    },
);

/**
 * Log user in
 * Checks if there is no user and if there is no
 * callback occuring within the window url which throws into
 * infinite loop, then login, and redirect to SSO login
 * @param {*} graphScopes
 */
export const signIn = async graphScopes => {
    console.log(graphScopes);
    /**
     * avoid duplicate code execution on page load in case of iframe and popup window
     */
    if (!userAgentApplication.getUser() && !userAgentApplication.isCallback(window.location.hash)) {
        /**
         * login site, and go directly to SSO
         */
        await userAgentApplication.loginRedirect(graphScopes, process.env.REACT_APP_DOMAIN);
        /**
         * acquireTokenSilent method makes a silent request to ADD to obtain an access token.
         * ADD returns an access token containing the user consented scopes to allow
         * the app to securely call the api
         */
        await userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent(graphScopes);
    }
};

/**
 * Logs user out
 */
export const logOut = () => userAgentApplication.logout();
```

This is what I get when I use jwt.ms:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aren't those scopes for Graph API and not your API? Where do you request a token for your API?

Comment: hi @juunas thanks for your quick reply. I'm not sure I follow the first part of your question. The scopes are intended for the graphAPI I think, `loginRedirect()` belongs to the `MSAL()` object. I request my token from `graph.windows`

Comment: You are requesting an access token for Graph API. That is not your API so it does not respect your token version settings. You need to change the scopes to match your API's identifier.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I see what you mean. How would I go about finding the correct scopes to match my API's Identifier? BTW, I appreciate your time and patience. If you want you can post this as an actual answer, this is really helping me understand the inner workings of ADD @juunas

Comment: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Adal-to-Msal#scopes-for-a-web-api-accepting-v10-tokens shows you some examples. You would normally use the app id URI + /.default or some specific scopes. I can't remember if it was different if you want to use the same app registration for the client and API.

Comment: You can create an app id URI from the Azure portal if one doesn't already exist for the API

Comment: I've been going at it for a while, doing this `var scopes = [ resourceURI + "/.default"];
acquireSilentToken(scopes);` and using it in my `loginRedirect(scopes)` throws me into an infinite redirect loop :/. The resource URI, I obtain from portal.azure as you suggest @juunas

Comment: Uh, that's weird :/ Can you update the code in the question and possibly try to look into the requests and responses happening, see if you can see some errors and add them here as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to request an V1 access token from the V2 endpoint.  The type of access token (v1 or v2) that is issued to your client application is **determined by the application registration of the resource API**.  As others point out, your example code requests a Microsoft Graph scope and the Microsoft Graph app registration is configured to accept v2 tokens.  You can determine what type of tokens your API is configured to accept by looking at the app registration.  In **portal.azure.com**, open "**App registrations (Preview)**", go to the "**Manifest**" section, and look for the property "**accessTokenAcceptedVersion**".  If it is set to **null** or **1**, then all client applications requesting access tokens to call this resource will get a v1 access token (regardless if they use MSAL or ADAL to request the access token).

A common calling pattern for an ADAL app calling v1 resource API was to provide the resource URI as the scope.  This told the endpoint to issue an access token for all of the permissions configured in the app registration of the resource API.  MSAL (which uses the v2 endpoint) allows for requesting any scope regardless if it's in the static list of scopes of the app registration for a resource.  To get the same behavior as ADAL (which uses the v1 endpoint), append ".default" to the resource URI (e.g. "https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/V1TodoListService/.default")

At Ignite, I gave a demo of an existing to-do-list service that accepts only v1 access tokens, and I walk through the entire portal configuration of my new MSAL client application to request v1 access tokens and call this service.  Watch it here: https://youtu.be/77A47CfNqIU?t=3120

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you know about adding the .default to your resource URI ?

Comment: @saeed-akhter Do you know what would be the resource (scope) for the CRM? From what you've said something like `https://crm-instance.crm4.dynamics.com/.default` should be the case. There is no error while acquiring token but there is wrong audience defined in it, and when the token is used, the CRM gives 401. The token from MSAL has aud defined as:  `00000007-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`,
and token from adal has: `https://crm-instance.crm4.dynamics.com`

Comment: @CircusRanger one possibility - are you requesting more than one scope including one of the other scopes for Microsoft Graph?  It is possible to have a list of scopes for multiple audiences to minimize the number of consent screens the end user sees, but then to get access tokens for each one it’s necessary to make separate requests to collect an access token using just the scopes relevant to that audience.

Comment: @saeed-akhter I've tried all of the combinations. With and without graphApi resource (scopes). I basically haven't succeed to acquire the token (via MSAL) for the DynamicsCRM (only for CRM). The same application User, settings, etc. works fine with ADAL. What I tried to define is protectedResourceMap and consentScopes fields. The aggravating factor is that the MSAL acquires the token without any error but it's not working when I try to access the CRM webapi endpoint. Do you have any hint how MsalModule.forRoot object should look alike for D365?

Comment: @CircusRanger, thanks for confirming scopes wasn't the issue.  I'm currently out on vacation, but I messaged a couple folks in the office to take a look.  Is there any sample code you could upload on GitHub that reproduces the issue?  That might help them accelerate their investigation.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Saeed. @CircusRanger could you send a Fiddler trace of both the ADAL and MSAL token acquisitions to hirsin at microsoft.com ? Or the tokens themselves - that will let us check our telemetry on the backend and verify how they're being generated.

Comment: Currently I have a problem with using logging into the SPA. Project hasn't been modified over the weekend but neither my colleague nor me can log into the application anymore. Something strange is happening as our last commit is almost 3 months old and it was working the same way until today... We'll send the tokens if we make it work again..