# AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi .net core 5 web api ? will this support version V1 and V2 Api ? MSAL

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, adal, azure-authentication

i m using react my front end using ADAL.js and my back end using
MSAL ### below is code

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))

as my front app use ADAL.js its create V1 token and in back end i have MSAL ?
how i can support this situation ?

as i want to impose my back end to understand V1 token which is created by front app ADAL.js

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to request an V1 access token and even V2 depending on the requirement. .

But please check which token the API needs as:

1. **Idtoken:** If you ask for an ID token from the **V1 endpoint**, you get a V1 ID token. If you ask for an ID token from the V2
   endpoint you get a V2 ID token.
   [image]
2. **Accesstoken:** Access Tokens versions are determined by the **configuration of your application/API in the manifest**.

The access token type (v1 or v2) which is  issued to your app is determined by the application registration of the resource API.

You can determine which type of tokens your API is configured to accept making small change or seeing what is present in app registration. In portal,when you go to the "Manifest" section, and check for **"accessTokenAcceptedVersion"**. If it is set to null or 1, then all client applications requesting access tokens to call this resource will get a v1 access token (***Regardless if they use MSAL or ADAL to request the access token***).
[image]
And you may need  to request a **scope with /.default** *for example: https://database.windows.net//.default*

According to [Scopes for v1.0 apps (MSAL) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-v1-app-scopes#scopes-to-request-access-to-specific-oauth2-permissions-of-a-v10-application)

> **NOTE:**
>
> - For ADAL with a v1.0 access token , aud=resource
> - For MSAL  accepting v2.0 tokens, aud=resource.AppId
> - For MSAL v2.0 endpoint getting  an access token for a resource that    accepts a v1.0 access token (which is the case above), Azure AD
>   parses the desired audience from the requested scope by taking
>   everything before the last slash and using it as the resource
>   identifier. Therefore, if https://database.windows.net expects an
>   audience of https://example.com/, you'll need to request a
>   scope of https://example.com/.default

**Reference :** [authentication - Is it possible to obtain an Azure AD V1 token using MSAL? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54368394/is-it-possible-to-obtain-an-azure-ad-v1-token-using-msal)